# Can you have circle shadows on hover with plain Tailwind CSS?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I recently started learning Tailwind CSS because based on some research about the job market, I felt like it would be a nice marketable skill for my area.

Anyway, I am currently making a website in which I am trying to restrict myself from writing any other CSS classes apart from the ones given to me by Tailwind (In order to familiarize myself with "Tailwind Solutions" to certain problems). However I am kind of running into a dead end with a specific "issue".

I have a couple of circle "buttons" (they are images to be precise, but they have an "onClick" action). Instead of letting the user stumble upon the existence of this button randomly, I wanted to add a hover effect to the button so that a shadow appears around the image when the pointer is hovered on top of the image.

I have only tried the straightforward **`hover: shadow-sm`** class but I kind of expected this not to work because this is labeled in the Tailwind Docs as a "box-shadow". However I couldn't find anything else that could be applied in my case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I realise it's not exactly a shadow effects, but you could look into the [`ring-` utilities](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/ring-color). You'll need to explicitly enable the `hover` variant in the config, as it's not enabled by default.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the response. As far as I can see, rings just outline elements. That won't really work with what I have because even though the images have a circle shape they are actually inside a div square container (it's a png). So wherever I apply the ring property, it will just be a boxy outline around the image. Unless I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong, that's how they work. Sadly, I can't think of anything else that would work the way you want using only Tailwind utilities.

Comment: Well, if it can't be done at all with Tailwind then I guess that's fine. Guess I'll have to use some extra CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around with positioning & created this [shadow on hover](https://play.tailwindcss.com/2CZb2gh4eP).

Check out and keep me posted in the comments below.